# Does Anyone Know How to Understand Such Kind of Perl Code Blocks?

Tags: perl

I'm confused by Perl Named Blocks (I thought they are...). Below is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub Run(&){
  my ($decl) = @_;
  $decl->();  
}

sub cmd(&){
  my($decl)   = @_;
  my(@params) = $decl->();
  print "@params\n";
}
sub expect(&){
  my ($decl) = @_;  
  my(@params) = $decl->();
  print "@params\n";
}

Run {
  cmd { "echo hello world " };
  expect { exit_code => 0, capture => 2}; 
};
```

Note the last lines. It looks like "Run", "cmd", "expect" are named blocks, but not functions. Does anyone know what they are? Any available link introduces them?
I can't find any reference for such grammar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's decipher this definition for `Run`:

```
sub Run(&){
  my ($decl) = @_;
  $decl->();  
}
```

It means subroutine called `Run`, which accepts parameter of type `CODE` (that's why it uses `(&)`). Inside it `$decl` gets assigned to that passed code, and this code gets called by `$decl->();`.

Now, last lines in your example:

```
Run {
  cmd { "echo hello world " };
  expect { exit_code => 0, capture => 2}; 
};
```

are equivalent to:

```
Run(sub {
  cmd { "echo hello world " };
  expect { exit_code => 0, capture => 2}; 
});
```

In other words, it calls `Run` with anonymous procedure code that is in braces.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

`Run`, `cmd`, and `expect` are [`prototype`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) defined functions, and they work like built-in functions (no need to write `sub{..}`, as this is implicit due `(&)` signature for these functions).

If these functions were defined without prototypes,

```
sub Run { .. }
sub cmd { .. }
sub expect { .. }
```

then explicit `sub{}` arguments would be not optional but required,

```
Run(sub{
  cmd(sub{ "echo hello world " });
  expect(sub{ exit_code => 0, capture => 2}); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

They are subroutines accepting block as an argument. See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes. The `(&)` in their definitions means that their first argument is a block of code.